# Multiple controls with the same ID 'xyz' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a single aspx page in my web-app which shows some asp.net charts/tables/repeaters etc.

Now, when the user access the page and leave it idle for some time and click 
submit-button or ctrl+F5(refresh), then following exception occurs at random.

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'xyz' were found. FindControl
>   requires that controls have unique IDs.

and the thing is it has thrown exception for most of the control's on my page
like labels, chart, textBox, scriptManager etc

I am unable to get the cause of these random exceptions or get what I am doing wrong in my code.

I have not dynamically generated any of the control's unique id ( from code-behind) and none of the id is duplicated on the page.

I have used Ajax control toolkit ( 7.0.x)
Also at code behind I have used System.Threading.task to bind the charts/repeaters.

My ASPX file is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="Report.Dashboard" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>title1</title>
    <link href="css/Report.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/Report.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divHeader">
        <table class="dataTable">
            <tr style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
                <td style="min-width: 75%;">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td class="headerUserName">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server" Style="" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" class="userName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 100%;">
                <td class="columnWithImage" colspan="2">
                    <img alt="LOGO" src="images/logo.png" width="259" height="38" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="divMain" class="marginT10">
        <div id="divLeftSegment">
        </div>
        <div id="divImgLoading" class="divModalBackground">
            <img id="imgLoading" class="loaderImage" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="divFormSegment">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="divMainSegment">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="smScriptManager" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <div id="divQueryHeader">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" ContentEditable="false" Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="cldrStartDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartDate">
                                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" CssClass="margingL15" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ContentEditable="false" Width="125px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="cldrEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate">
                                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMinTotal" CssClass="margingL15" runat="server" Text="Min. Total Bill"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinTotal" runat="server" Width="125px" onkeypress="return IsOneDecimalPoint(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtenderMinTotal" runat="server"
                                    FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="01234567890." TargetControlID="txtMinTotal">
                                </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMaxTotal" CssClass="margingL15" runat="server" Text="Max. Total Bill"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaxTotal" runat="server" Width="125px" onkeypress="return IsOneDecimalPoint(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtenderMaxTotal" runat="server"
                                    FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="01234567890." TargetControlID="txtMaxTotal">
                                </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="margingL15"
                                    Width="100px" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="showLoadingImg();" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style="height: Auto;">
                    <div id="div3">
                        <div id="div4" runat="server">
                            <table style="width: 98%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Chart ID="chart1" runat="server" Width="500px">
                                            <Series>
                                                <asp:Series ChartType="Pie" Name="series1" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"
                                                    XValueMember="Category" YValueMembers="Count">
                                                </asp:Series>
                                            </Series>
                                            <ChartAreas>
                                                <asp:ChartArea Name="chartArea1">
                                                </asp:ChartArea>
                                            </ChartAreas>
                                            <Legends>
                                                <asp:Legend Name="legend1" Docking="Bottom">
                                                </asp:Legend>
                                            </Legends>
                                            <Titles>
                                                <asp:Title Name="title1" Text="Category">
                                                </asp:Title>
                                            </Titles>
                                        </asp:Chart>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Chart ID="chart2" runat="server" Width="500px">
                                            <Series>
                                                <asp:Series Name="series1" XValueMember="Age" YValueMembers="Count"
                                                    ToolTip="#VALY">
                                                </asp:Series>
                                            </Series>
                                            <ChartAreas>
                                                <asp:ChartArea Name="chartArea1">                                                 
                                                </asp:ChartArea>
                                            </ChartAreas>
                                            <Titles>
                                                <asp:Title Name="title1" Text="Age">
                                                </asp:Title>
                                            </Titles>
                                        </asp:Chart>
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>                      
                        <div id="div5" class="marginT15" runat="server">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table class="tbl1" rules="all" border="1">                                     
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="tableColHeader">
                                                Name
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="tableColHeader">
                                                Address
                                            </td>                                         
                                        </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="cellStyle">
                                            <%# Eval("Name")%>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="tableCellStyle">
                                            <%# Eval("Address")%>
                                        </td>  
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                        <div id="div6" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is far too broad, please read the [faq]. You need to ask more **specific** questions.

Comment: Where is the markup ?

Comment: @tariq - I have added the aspx

Comment: which id does it say is not unique, whats the name ?

Comment: basically I have received this error for lblStartDate, lblEndDate, smScriptManager, chart1 and other controls on the page.

Comment: What are you doing in your code behind?

Comment: @timothyclifford code behind just holds the bind of charts.
For binding I used tasks, which send separate request to business layer to extract data and on callback bind it to the chart/repeater

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was the callback methods in ContinueWith the task.
I removed all of the continueWith methods
and called them after Tasks.WaitAll()